# python: доступ к членам класса как переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, getter

подскажите можно ли в питоне (и если можно, то как) реализовать следующий функционал:

у класса

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, value, state):
        self.value = value
        self.state =  state

c = Object('test', 3.14)
```

при использовании `c` будет использоваться `value`:

```
print(c) # test
a = "b" + c # btest
```

при этом можно будет использовать и `c.state`:

```
print(c.state) # 3.14
x = c.state - 3 # 0.14
```

P.S.

и было бы вообще идеально, чтобы до `c.value` вообще нельзя было бы добраться, как будто его и нет

Comment: А вам надо вообще свободно `с` использовать в любых операциях или  в каких-то конкретных? С перегрузкой операций можно повозиться. Там такой эффект есть (см.более короткий комментарий об этом в ответе @Dmitry).

Comment: @Сергей - в любых операциях. Вообще наверное нужен кардинально другой подход - изначально мне нужно к ЛЮБОЙ переменной `x` подвестить дополнительное свойство `.state` и если это можно сделать как-то еще - буду рад

Comment: Советую внести обновить текст вопроса тогда. Я, к сожалению, на такой вопрос уже не отвечу уверенно.

Answer (score 2):

В данном конкретном случае можно просто унаследоваться от класса `str` и добавить нужное поле при инициализации:

```py
class Object(str):

    def __new__(cls, value, state):
        instance = super().__new__(cls, value)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, value, state):
        self.state = state
```

Поведение будет ровно такое, как вы хотите.

Но если нужны и другие виды данных в качестве первого аргумента, то придётся ещё подумать.

Comment: А вот и реализация подъехала с переопределением `__new__`,  =) +

Comment: @Dmitry А, я комментарии то толком и не читал )

Comment: @CrazyElf, со строкой понятно, но если тип данных неизвестен изначально - т.е. нужен тип как у некоторой переменной `x` - что-то типа `class Object(type(x))`

Answer (score 2):

Вы ищете идеальный прокси, т.е. такой который будет доступ (почти) ко всем атрибутам и ко всем специальным методам (типа `__repr__`, `__add__`, `__iter__` и т.д.) перенаправлять к обернутому объекту.

В общем случае это задача нерешаемая, так как в чем-то объект будет отличаться, например `type(c)` будет `Object`, а не `type(value)`, но можно довольно близко к этому подойти.

Вручную в общем случае это делать муторно (хоть и можно), нужно использовать `__getattribute__`/`__getattr__` для обычных атрибутов (в `__getattribute__` проверять если идет обращение к дополнительным атрибутам типа `state`, которых нет в заворачиваемом объекте), а так же вручную прописать перенаправление для всех специальных методов.

Проще использовать [ObjectProxy](https://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrappers.html) из библиотеки `wrapt`. Дополнительный атрибут должен иметь префикс `_self_`, чтоб `ObjectProxy` доступ к нему не перенаправлял к завернутому объекту:

```
class CustomProxy(wrapt.ObjectProxy):

    def __init__(self, value, state):
        super(CustomProxy, self).__init__(value)
        self._self_state = state

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self._self_state

    @attribute.setter
    def state(self, value):
        self._self_state = value
```

Answer (score 1):

В python есть возможность использование двойного знака подчеркивания, чтобы закрыть доступ по обращению через точку вот так

```py
class Object:
    def __init__(self, value, state):
        self.__value = value
        self.state =  state
```

Пример

```py
>>> c = Object(1,2) 
>>> c.__value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute '__value'
```

Но это не говорит, что до этого значения не добраться.

А вот `c` все равно будет хранить экземпляр класса, если не переопределить стандартный метод `__new__`, что и реализовано в ответе от [@CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/260769/crazyelf)

Comment: согласен, я скорее имел в виду кардинально переделать класс, чтобы вообще отсутствовала переменная `value`. Мне нужно просто к любой переменной `value` подвесить вспомогательное свойство `state` к которому можно получить доступ через точку, чтобы можно было использовать как я написал в примере

Comment: @Zhihar дела... А куда залезть то? Если идти вниз по вызовам. При создании вызывается `__call__`, тот в свою очередь вызывает `__new__`, где и возвращается объект, а к этому объекту уже применяется `__init__`. Может `__new__` переопределить? И вернуть не объект, а значение нужное вам. Но это выглядит, как пушкой по воробьям. Хм

Comment: Так то доступ всё-равно будет, просто поле будет называться чуть сложнее `c._Object__state` )

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать строковое представление обьекта

```py
class Object:
    def __init__(self, value, state):
        self.value = value
        self.state =  state

    def __str__(self):
      return self.value



c = Object('test', 3.14)
 
print(c) # test
print("b" + str(c)) #btest
```

или переопределить `__add__`, но в таком случае мы должны к обьекту добавлять строку, так же внутри `__add__` можно определить разную логику сложения в зависимости от того какого типа обьект мы прибавляем

```py
class Object:
    def __init__(self, value, state):
        self.value = value
        self.state =  state

    def __str__(self):
      return self.value

    def __add__(self, value):
      return self.value + value

c = Object('test', 3.14)

print(c) # test
print(c + "b") #testb
```